# NFS user permissions issue

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, centos, storage, nfs

I’m having a very strange problem with ownership of files in an NFS share.

All of the servers that I'm using are CentOS 6.5, and the version of nfs-utils that I'm using is nfs-utils-1.2.3-39.

On my storage server (where the actual NFS share exists), I have a tomcat user and a tomcat group, with a user ID of 91 and a group ID of 91.  I can create the directories that I want to share and chmod them to tomcat:tomcat.

On my client server, I can successfully mount the shared space.  I also have a tomcat user and a tomcat group, with a user ID of 91 and a group ID of 91.  I create files and directories inside the share from my client server, with the files being owned by tomcat:tomcat.

On the storage server, I can indeed see that the new files now exist and are owned by tomcat:tomcat.  But on the client server, the files are owned by nobody:nobody (uid:gid of 99:99).

After a bit of digging, I reverted the client server, deleted the contents of the shared directories and changed the ownership of the shared directories on the storage server to nobody:nobody  (uid:gid of 99:99), then I rebuilt the client server.  The same problem still exists.

What am I doing wrong, and how can I resolve it?  I need the shared directories to be owned by tomcat:tomcat, and I need to be able to create files from the client server inside the shared directories, with the files also owned by tomcat:tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

On your NFS-server, you have `root_squash` set - all requests to NFS are then translated into an anonymous user (this is the normal NFS behaviour). Reconfigure your NFS if needed.